# Issue in auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword() login

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

The login function in my code using auth is not working.Here is the code:

```
function login(){
  var email = document.getElementById("emailid").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("pass_word").value;
  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  if (errorCode === 'auth/wrong-password') {
    alert('Wrong password.');
  } else {
    alert(errorMessage);
  }
  console.log(error);
});
}
```

Anything that we write inside login but before and after

> firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword()

method is working.And if i try to write anything inside that is not working.Not even an alert message also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

is a method that return a **Promise** when it's executed, so you need to call

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(res => {
        //YOUR_CODE_HERE
})
```

To react to a successfull execution

A complete tutorial to achieve the login process is availible here : https://www.positronx.io/firebase-authentication-in-angular-8-with-angularfire2/

Comment: i tried this method also.But still no use.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable sign in with email in the `firebase` console.
If you don't then it will not work.

Comment: Yes i did it  also.

Answer (score 0):

did you have an account when doing that if you want to create an account then you should use [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#create_a_password-based_account)

not `signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)` that only works for an existing account.

Comment: i have already an account.I m just trying to signin